# Drupal - Core User Module

Tags: php, validation, drupal

I have added a button in the form and upon clicking it performs different set of action. The problem i am facing is that the default form is also submitted and i get the velidation messages like enter email etc.

Please advise.

Comment: How did you add additional buttons to the form?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what it is you are trying to do?  What are you trying to do with the new button?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot hijack a form like that. When a form is submitted, all enabled validate handlers will be called, and if no error is found all submit handlers is called.

If you want to make a multi-purpose form, with different requirements, you need to either create the form yourself and handle the validate, or use an existing form, and replace the existing validation with your own.

Comment: Yes i have multipurpose form. I have different button s made there like add another education detail, upgrade to gold member, silver member buttons etc.  So we upgrading to silver / gold member the default validation should not be called instead a function should be called which changes the user type. I am new to Drupal so please send an example. Also the new button should be between the items of registration form.